# How to S-Off on HTC One M7, HBOOT-1.61

Tags: htc-one, t-mobile, s-off

I have a HTC ONE M7 purchased from T-Mobile. I rooted it and have CyanogenMod installed in it. Recently, I switched to different carrier. Now, my phone rejects foreign sim card and asks for Network SIM card lock. The unlock code provided by T-Mobile doesn't work due to rooting the phone.

I want to go back to T-Mobile Android stock ROM and try the unlock code. What's the process for it? Here are some details from bootloader screen:

*** TAMPERED ***

*** UNLOCKED ***

M7_UL PVT SHIP S-ON RH

HBOOT-1.61.0000

RADIO-4T.35.3218.16

OpenDSP-v35.120.274.0718

OS-7.18.531.2

eMMC-boot 2048MB

Feb 11, 2015, 18:39:53.0

Apart from help in doing S-OFF, I would appreciate if someone points me to right link for going back to Stock ROM.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to get S-OFF on HTC One M7 hboot 1.61 is [SunShine](http://theroot.ninja/) application which costs 25$. I was also searching for it and finally found [Sunshine](http://theroot.ninja/) is the only working solution.

[image]

Here is the [HowTo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1CM4jxm28U) video about the application.

Comment: Adding key steps from the video would be helpful. There is no guarantee that the video will stay on you tube and when it is removed, your answer is of no use